# Localhost causing issues with external websites, joomla components

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, apache, localhost

I have recently come across an issue where my Localhost Apache server (and/or MySQL server) will interfere with some random websites.

Most recently I discovered the localhost was causing issues on a Joomla website were a single component would throw a 404 component not found error.

since 99% or more of the web continues to work correctly I assume there are 2 primary causes and 3 possible solutions.

Causes
 1. code issues with the website/Joomla component
 2. localhost apache configuration issues

solutions

1. Fix the code issues (if it's your site/component)
2. fix the issue with the localhost configuration
3. stop the localhost server when your surfing the web

I need guidance on what in php code for a Joomla component would cause such issues, and how to fix those code issues.
I would hate to see someone happen to have a localhost instance running and have an issue with one of my sites.

Answer (score 1):

Changing Apache from port 80 to port 81, or anything else, should solve this issue without haveing to stop Apache.